# how to search using AND & LIKE OR operator in asingle query

Tags: mysql

I am designing a library management system I want to design a pending request page that select and displays all information from the issue_book table where column status=pending. my point is to design a search field that search a specific row from the information available in a pending request page but it does not produce any output please my friend i need help

```
   public List<Issue_Use_Bean> search_pending_history(String search){
                    Connection connection=null;
                    DBConnection_LMS_Portal obj_DBConnection_SMS_Portal=new 
   DBConnection_LMS_Portal();
                    connection=obj_DBConnection_SMS_Portal.getConnection();
                    PreparedStatement ps=null;
                    ResultSet rs=null;
                    List<Issue_Use_Bean> list=new ArrayList<Issue_Use_Bean>();

                try { 


    String query="select * from issue_book where status='Pending' AND employee_id 
    like ? or book_title like ? or barcode like ? or issue_date like ? or return_date like ?  or 
    description like ? order by issue_date desc limit 500";
                    ps=connection.prepareStatement(query);
                    ps.setString(1, search);
                    ps.setString(2, "%"+search+"%");
                    ps.setString(3, "%"+search+"%");
                    ps.setString(4, "%"+search+"%");
                    ps.setString(5, "%"+search+"%");
                    ps.setString(6, "%"+search+"%");
                    ps.setString(7, "%"+search+"%");

                    System.out.println(ps);
                    rs=ps.executeQuery();

                    while(rs.next()){
                        Issue_Use_Bean obj_Issue_Use_Bean=new Issue_Use_Bean();

                      obj_Issue_Use_Bean.setStatus(rs.getString("status"));
                        obj_Issue_Use_Bean.setEmployee_id(rs.getString("employee_id"));
                        obj_Issue_Use_Bean.setBook_title(rs.getString("book_title"));

                        obj_Issue_Use_Bean.setBarcode(rs.getString("barcode"));
                        obj_Issue_Use_Bean.setIssue_date(rs.getString("issue_date"));
                        obj_Issue_Use_Bean.setReturn_date(rs.getString("return_date"));
                        obj_Issue_Use_Bean.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
                        obj_Issue_Use_Bean.setIssue_sl_no(rs.getString("issue_sl_no"));

                        list.add(obj_Issue_Use_Bean);
                        }





                 }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    if(connection!=null){
                        try {
                                connection.close();
                            }
                            catch (Exception e2) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                            }
                    }
                    if(ps!=null){
                        try {

                            ps.close();
                            }
                         catch (Exception e2) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                        }
                    }
                    if(rs!=null){
                        try {

                            rs.close();
                            }
                         catch (Exception e2) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                        }
                    }

            }

                return list;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need parentheses to nest the part with **or** operators :

```
select * 
  from issue_book 
 where status='Pending' 
   and (   employee_id like ? 
        or book_title like ? 
        or barcode like ? 
        or issue_date like ? 
        or return_date like ? 
        or description like ? ) 
 order by issue_date desc limit 500
```

Answer (score 0):

tnx to Barbaros Ozhan he gives me the following a good hint:
and there must be 6(six) ps.setString(); for LIKEOR operator not for AND operator because it search criteria is already defined.
    select * 
    from issue_book 
    where status='Pending' 
    and (   employee_id like ? 
        or book_title like ? 
        or barcode like ? 
        or issue_date like ? 
        or return_date like ? 
        or description like ? ) 
    order by issue_date desc limit 500

```
       ps=connection.prepareStatement(query);
                    ps.setString(1, "%"+search+"%");
                    ps.setString(2, "%"+search+"%");
                    ps.setString(3, "%"+search+"%");
                    ps.setString(4, "%"+search+"%");
                    ps.setString(5, "%"+search+"%");
                    ps.setString(6, "%"+search+"%");


                    System.out.println(ps);
                    rs=ps.executeQuery();

                    while(rs.next()){
                        Issue_Use_Bean obj_Issue_Use_Bean=new Issue_Use_Bean();

        obj_Issue_Use_Bean.setStatus(rs.getString("status"));        
        obj_Issue_Use_Bean.setEmployee_id(rs.getString("employee_id"));
        obj_Issue_Use_Bean.setBook_title(rs.getString("book_title"));                                                                   
        obj_Issue_Use_Bean.setBarcode(rs.getString("barcode"));
        obj_Issue_Use_Bean.setIssue_date(rs.getString("issue_date"));    
        obj_Issue_Use_Bean.setReturn_date(rs.getString("return_date"));                  
        obj_Issue_Use_Bean.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));              
        obj_Issue_Use_Bean.setIssue_sl_no(rs.getString("issue_sl_no"));
        list.add(obj_Issue_Use_Bean);
                        }
```